# Electron - how to fetch a file from a local path and create a blob file

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron

I have this code in my background.js file of an electron app.

```js
ipcMain.on('init', (event, ...args) => {
    fileSelector = dialog.showOpenDialog({
        title: 'Select template',
        buttonLabel: 'Upload file',
        filters: [
            {
                name: 'MS Word document', extensions: ['docx']
            }
        ]
    }).then( (filePath) => {
        //fs.readFile(filePath.filePaths[0], (err, data) => {
            event.sender.send('documentPath', filePath.filePaths[0])
        //})
    }).catch( (error) => console.warn(error) )
})
```

Basically I'm opening a native file selector and I will send the path on the vue front end of the app

```js
        ipcRenderer.send('init')
        ipcRenderer.receive('documentPath', (filePath) => {
            //this.store.docTemplate = new Blob(data, { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' }).arrayBuffer()
            fs.readFile(filePath, (error, data) => {
                this.store.docTemplate = data
            })
            console.log(this.store.docTemplate)
        })
```

I'm calling the listener on the `ipcRenderer` in the mounted hook of vuejs. What I need to do is to read the file from the received file path and obtain a blob like will occur normally if the desired file is obtained using an `<input type="file">`. I need to pass the blob to [this library](https://github.com/alonrbar/easy-template-x), so is there a way to accomplish this? I've tried to enable the node integration, but this will give me problems with ipc processes.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what is not working about your code just from looking at your example, but calling `fs.readFile` in your renderer code will generally not work. Instead of sending the file path to your renderer and reading the file there, why not just call `fs.readFile` in your `background.js` and send the binary data to the renderer? If you could provide more details on what is failing, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in the comments and some local testing, it has become apparent that `easy-template-x` does not seem to support `ArrayBuffer` objects in the browser, despite the README saying it does.

However, that is not a problem because you can completely handle the template in your main thread. That's where this kind of stuff should be done anyways so that your renderers can do more renderer stuff. It's best to take advantage of that second process as much as possible. JS has only a single thread, so having two processes is a real luxury!

I've modified your example code to show how that would be done and used `async/await` to make everything more readable. You might need to add some more checks around that, but it worked just fine for me using `easy-template-x@3.1.0

I've also changed your `send/on/receive` structure to a simpler one that uses `ipcRenderer.invoke` paired with `ipcMain.handle` The advantage is that the main process can return a response to the call, which allows some form of bidirectional communication. For more info, see [this page of the Electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)

`main.js`

```js
const { readFile, writeFile } = require("fs/promises");
const { TemplateHandler } = require("easy-template-x");

ipcMain.handle("processTemplate", async (event, args) => {
  const loadDialog = await dialog.showOpenDialog({
    title: "Select template",
    buttonLabel: "Upload file",
    filters: [
      {
        name: "MS Word document",
        extensions: ["docx"],
      },
    ],
  });

  const selected = loadDialog.filePaths[0];

  if (selected) {
    const file = await readFile(selected);
  
    const handler = new TemplateHandler();
    const doc = await handler.process(file, params);
  
    const saveDialog = await dialog.showSaveDialog({
      title: "Save document",
      buttonLabel: "Save document",
      filters: [
        {
          name: "MS Word document",
          extensions: ["docx"],
        },
      ],
    });
    
    if (saveDialog.filePath) {
      await writeFile(saveDialog.filePath, doc);
    }
  }
});
```

`preload.js`

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("templates", {
  processTemplate: (params) => ipcRenderer.invoke("processTemplate", params),
});
```

`renderer.js`

```js
async function process() {
  await window.templates.processTemplate(templateParams);
}
```

If anything about that code is unclear or you have more questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: I've tried that solutiuon, but the library if invoked from the renderer will not accept different file format other than blob. So if I pass the array buffer from nackground process to the renderer it will not be recognized and I will unable to generate the docx template

Comment: Hm, that's strange. I'll build an example using that library and see if I can find something. I'll get back to you once I'm done, should not take too long.

Comment: Ok, thank you. At the moment I'm using a temporary solution to get the blob, but I will wait for your suggestion.

Comment: @ICTDEV just a quick question: how is `easy-template-x` being loaded in your renderer? Do you have a `script` tag in your `index.html` or are you using any bundler?

Comment: no, it's imported using import ES6 syntax, basically I'm creating a vuejs app for the front-end of my electron app. The bundler is vite that actually is the default used by vue projects

Comment: Okay, I think I found out what's wrong: I didn't read the part of the README about the supported formats and gave you code that passed a Node.js `Buffer` into the browser, where - as you said - a `Blob` is expected. The README also says that both environments _should_ support `ArrayBuffer`s, but even if I get one from a `Blob` that itself is working just fine, using `ArrayBuffer`s will fail in the browser. The important question now is: What do need to do with the processed file? Do you want to display it or just save it back to disk?

Comment: Yes mate, for a strange reason the browser will not see the `ArrayBuffer` correctly. I need the file to use it as a template where automatically I will replace sone tags with dynamic informations. I will need to save back the file, but for this I've used a quick workaround that will consist into create an `<a>` tag and set it with the download attribute and a data url

Comment: not sure if there is a function in electron to achive this instead of the solution described in the previous comment

Comment: Good news then! In that case, there's actually no good reason to do any of the template handling in your renderer at all :) You can simply process the template in your main process and save it back using a native Electron dialog. I'll update my answer to show how, so it answers the question correctly.

Comment: ok, essentially the same code I have in my methods to process the template and do the replacing of the tags, will work also in the backend process. I just will need to send a command to the background.js file, to be honest I didn't thinked to this initialli when I've strated developing the app. Thank you for the tip

Comment: Exactly. It took me a while to get used to working like this, but it's straightforward once you get the hang of it. If it helps, you can think of your main process as the "server" of your app that does the heavy work. The renderers are the clients doing only what's needed to send some input data to that "server" and display its response.

Comment: I see in your example that you've used `window.templates.processTemplate(templateParams);` what do you have binded to the window?

Comment: Have a look at the `preload.js` script in my answer. The first parameter to `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld` is the name of the object that should be created in `window` by the preload script. The second parameter is the object itself. You should *never* expose `ipcRenderer` directly to your `renderers`, but should _always_  use a preload script. See [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) and [here for more info](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-2-renderer-to-main-two-way).

Comment: I've noticed that after the template is populated with data, the function `fs.writeFile` will not save the file into the position I will define. Not sure why, this is very strange, any help?

Comment: Sounds strange indeed. It worked when I tested it on my machine, so I'll have to guess. Do you alter the selected path in any way before passing it into `writeFile`? Double check using a breakpoint or a console log that the path is in fact the one you want. Also, are you using `writeFile` from `fs` or from `fs/promises`? Not that I know about any difference, but just to be on the same page.